# React Native error: Export namespace should be first transformed by `@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, babeljs

I am getting the following error when I am running react native application using `react-native-cli`

```
error: node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\index.ts: 
D:\Desktop\coding\Github\Stocksy\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\index.ts: 
Export namespace should be first transformed by `@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from`.
```

I am attaching the screenshot of error I am getting with my system configuration
[image]

System Config
[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this: -

1. `npm install react-native-reanimated`
2. In babel.config.js insert plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'] (make sure its at the end, it should look like this: -

   module.exports = {
   presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
   plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'],
   };
3. run react-native start --reset-cache
4. run your native app (For ios example - npx react-native run-ios)

Comment: If your using the 'react-native-paper' library make a separate plugins:['react-native-reanimated/plugin'] and below that use the babel config which is in the env for 'react-native-paper/babel' as per documentation.

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is add this config to your **babel.config.js** and restart your app.
**plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'],**